# How do I remove rows from a table I generated from an JQuery AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table, get

I'm writing a piece of code where:

1. user inputs a location,
2. clicks a button to make a GET call to retrieve data based on location, and
3. a table is populated from the data.

Each time the user clicks the button, I want to refresh the table contents, but right now it keeps appending. I wanted to write a `clearTable()` method but I've tried `.remove()`, `.parentNode.remove(table)`, `tr:gt(0).remove()`, etc... Without success.

`console.log()` shows that the table only has one row (the header) at time of clearing. I didn't include my `clearTable()` code since I've tried a lot of things and none of it worked, but I did show where I was trying to call it.

Also, not sure if related or not, but while my GET call seems to complete without issue, my browser's developer console shows

> An error occurred while trying to load the resource

My table code in HTML body:

```
<div class=ui-grid-b">
   <table id="locTable">
       <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Description</th>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#loadData').click(function (e) {
    if (getLocationInput() == '') {
        alert("Please enter a location.");
    }
    else {
        // clearTable(); <-- Currently not working
        var locData;
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'GET',
            'url': href,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'dataType': 'json',
            headers: { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + getAccessToken() },
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                locData = data;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                handleAjaxError(xhr, thrownError);
            }
        });

        // Appends table with values from data
        $(function() {
            $.each(locData.data, function(i, loc) {
                $('<tr>').append(
                $('<td>').text(loc.name),
                $('<td>').text(location.id),
                $('<td>').text(loc.description)).appendTo('#locTable');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post your clearTable function even if it isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete row from table dynamically created in javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147605/delete-row-from-table-dynamically-created-in-javascript)

Comment: How do you know `locData` has a result by the time you try to work with it in your `$.each()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful about using `locData` as it is given a value asynchronously.  The way you are using it now is likely not quite right.  That said, for your `clearTable()` I think you might find this helpful.

```
$("#locTable tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
```

Here is a demo:

```js
console.log("About to remove childen");

setTimeout(function(){
  $("#locTable tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
  console.log("childen removed");
}, 2 * 1000)
```

```html
<div class="ui-grid-b">
   <table id="locTable">
       <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Description</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th>a name</th>
           <th>an ID</th>
           <th>some Description</th>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you! I redid the code to use a callback instead of async:false and it seemed to solve the error I encountered as well.